# Are there any attributes to pre select some radio button in <h:selectOneRadio > tag on page lodads

Tags: jsf

Are there any attributes to pre select some radio button in  tag on page lodads

below is my code i want the Now radio button to be selected when page loads ,

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="Radios"
    value="#{pc_ClosureDecision.closureDetails.approvalDateSelected}"
    layout="lineDirection" onclick="check_Date()">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="now" itemLabel="Now" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="later" itemLabel="Resolve Later" />
</h:selectOneRadio></td>
```

Comment: FYI: instructions for posting code in the editor can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize `#{pc_ClosureDecision.closureDetails.approvalDateSelected}` with a value of `"now"` (in the Java code, or by injection in your `faces-config.xml`).

Comment: +1,Not exactly the same problem I was having, but by reading your answer I realized that the value attribute is not expecting a SelectItem from my backing bean, so I changed it to be the specific item value, now it's working. Thanks.